# Can someone tell me what's wrong with this java code?

Tags: java

I keep getting an error that looks like this and I can't figure out why:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
at Assignment20.main(Assignment20.java:17)
```

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Assignment20{



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    File myFile = new File("scores.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

while (input.hasNext()) {
  String firstName = input.next();
  String mi = input.next();
  String lastName = input.next();
  int score = input.nextInt();
  System.out.println(
    firstName + " " + mi + " " + lastName + " " + score);
}


input.close();


}
}
```

the text file i'm trying to get it to read looks like this

Harry Potter,72

Ron Weasley,68

Hermione Granger,98

Albus Dumbledore,90

Neville Longbottom,75

Luna Lovegood,86

Draco Malfoy,64

Cho Chang,88

Ginny Weasley,78

Tom Riddle,92

what do I need to do to fix this?

Edit: I changed the text file around, but it's still not working, I get the same error. Can someone show me the fixed code? I'm not understanding what I have to do.

Comment: hint: try printing out firstName, mi and lastName (before rying to read the int) and see what you get

Comment: Think a minute, look at the structure of your text file. Does it match the data you want to retrieve in your code ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `Scanner` delimiter is a space. So, one of your `next()` calls is consuming the last name as well as the score ("Potter,72" for example). Hence, the `nextInt()` call is failing.

Also, you seem to be trying to read four values when you have only two (considering the `Scanner` is treating the last name and score as one). Select either a space or a comma as your delimiter. If you choose to have comma-separated values then use `Scanner#useDelimiter(",")` as well.

```
Harry,Potter,72
Ron,Weasley,68
```

Considering the file format as above (csv) you can use the code below.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile).useDelimiter(",");

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] line = input.nextLine().split(",");
    String firstName = line[0];
    String lastName = line[1];
    int score = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
    System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + score);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Exception is self explanatory. There is mismatch in parameter you are reading and the type of parameter you are assigning it to.
Most likely area of error is `int score = input.nextInt();`

Just for debugging purpose, i would suggest to replace `int score = input.nextInt();` with `int score = input.next();` . This would help you to nail down the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your text file is not well structured, use space to separate values. And as your file does not contain any middle name, no need to retrieve one.

Change the structure of your text file as follow:

Scores.txt

```
Harry Potter 72
Ron Weasley 68
Hermione Granger 98
Albus Dumbledore 90
Neville Longbottom 75
Luna Lovegood 86
Draco Malfoy 64
Cho Chang 88
Ginny Weasley 78
Tom Riddle 92
```

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File myFile = new File("scores.txt");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String firstName = input.next();

        String lastName = input.next();

        int score = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + score);
    }

    input.close();

}
```

}

Comment: This gave me the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Assignment20.main(Assignment20.java:18)

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the text file in which you are placing the input to your program. First the format of the line in the text record should be like this `Tom Riddle , 92` and not `Tom Riddle,92`. the space between the middle name and the comma ',' and between the score should be there. Otherwise `Riddle,92` is read as a single token which causes and error when this token which is string is assigned to and integer `score`.